# Explain this: CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)sender;

Tags: c#, asp.net

While going through the checkBox I found there is written

```
CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)sender
```

on `checkBox1_CheckedChanged` event.

Please explain what it means?

Comment: You can see this example:
private void CheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TestTextBox.Enabled = ! ((CheckBox)sender).Checked;
}

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The line simply casts `sender` to a `CheckBox`.

Why?

The event handler signature for the `CheckedChanged` event is:

```
CheckChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

So, you need to cast `sender` back to a `CheckBox` if you want to use any `CheckBox` specific functionality - `object` doesn't have much that you can use...

This way the `checkbox` variable can be used to get the checkbox Id and operate on the checkbox.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example.Suppose in Gridview or Repeater we want select all option.As you have seen 
on your mail box.There a single checkbox if you click on it all will select.Code will better explain you.

```
protected void ChkAll_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (RepeaterItem rowItem in this.rptFriendsRecord.Items)
    {
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)rowItem.FindControl("cbFriend");
        chk.Checked = ((CheckBox)sender).Checked;
    }
}
```

I hope it works.

Answer (score 3):

I assume the method definition is something like this:

```
void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender,EventArgs e){
  CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)sender;
  //....
}
```

Basically what they are doing here is casting the `sender` variable which is declared as only a generic object into a (much more "useful") `CheckBox` variable.

This is commonly done because you have to cast to access the "specific" properties of a CheckBox.

For instance

```
sender.Checked=true;
```

will not work. You would have to do this:

```
((CheckBox)sender).Checked=true;
```

which of course is very ugly, so it's much easier to declare a new CheckBox variable and then you can simply do

```
checkbox.Checked=true;
```

with no casting.

Answer (score 1):

The `sender` parameter (which is declared as plain `Object`) is cast to `CheckBox` as you apparently know that the sender of that event always is a CheckBox.

Comment: I wish I could +1 you once more for using 'apparently' :)

Answer (score 1):

As [Oded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777766/eplain-this-checkbox-checkbox-checkboxsender/3777787#3777787) says, you need the cast because of the event handler signature.

You *could* use `checkBox1` in the event handler instead of the the typecast, but dealing with the `sender`, you can reuse the `CheckChanged` logic for other controls as well - although in that case, it should be refactored into something along the lines of:

```
private void MyFancyCheckChanged(CheckBox sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // do stuff
}

private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  MyFancyCheckChanged((CheckBox) sender, e);
}
```

Comment: You haven't gained anything by doing this. All you've done is set the table for a spaghetti warehouse.

Comment: @Joel: if you mean the method extraction, that depends on whether the code actually *is* of general use - in which case it should probably also be yanked out of the class and put somewhere more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The CheckBox class represents a check box that users can select and clear. This topic introduces you to the CheckBox control in Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) and describes how to create CheckBox elements in Extensible Application Markup Language (XAML) and C#, set event handlers in C#, create CheckBox controls that contain rich content such as images, and use styling to change the control's appearance.
Here i have given a sample for you .

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text="www.google.com" 
    OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" Text="www.yahoo.com" />
```

The Code Behind code is

```
protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (CheckBox1.Checked)
        Response.Redirect("www.google.com");
    else
        Response.Redirect("www.yahoo.com");
}
```